# How to achieve asp.net mvc action name with hyphen?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to achieve asp.net mvc action name with hyphen e.g., `www.domain.com/about-us` where `about-us` is the acton name in home controller. With this approach, i can achieve to have the action name like `contact-us`, `how-to`, etc.

Comment: Should be possible with routes as well

Answer (score 11):

Here's the complete working solution to the problem for a .Net MVC 5 project:

1. Open your project's **App_Start/RouteConfig.cs** file.
2. On your **RegisterRoute** method, modify the codes like this:

   ```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // <--- add this line to enable custom attribute routes

       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   }
   ```
3. Now, open your controller file then add your custom route's definition at the top your action as shown below:

   ```
   [Route("about-us")]
   public ActionResult AboutUs()
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

You should now be able to use your custom route like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/about-us
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. This method does not cause multiple routes mapping to the same content which is bad for SEO. With this method you also don't have to change the name of view (.cshtml) file.

Comment: What about MVC4? Is there a similar solution?

Comment: No idea with MVC4. Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

You can give your action name inside of `actionName` tag.

```
[ActionName("about-us")]
public ActionResult AboutUs() {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Note that using ActionName creates an alias to the action name; it doesn't change the action's name. There are side effects. [Read more here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053617/asp-mvc-actionnameattribute)

Comment: This method would cause duplicate content in most cases. With the default route configuration both /home/about-us and /about-us would map to the same content. And this is not recommended for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC5 you are able to set up attribute routes too:

```
    [Route("about-us")]
    public ActionResult AboutUs()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @JhourladEstrella I can confirm that it does work as I use this in my project. When referring to the action in your code-behind, you should still refer to it as AboutUs:

`Url.Action("AboutUs")` however the resulting URL will be `about-us`

Comment: He failed to mention the configuration prerequisites of his answer. Thus, the answer can't stand on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

In `AreaRegistration.cs` file, you can add route table entry as below.....

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "about_us_default",
            "about-us",
            new { action = "AboutUs" }
        );
```